# Can I set an alarm on Alexa or Google Home by sending a text message, through integration such as IFTTT?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, google-home, google-assistant-sdk, ifttt, google-assist-api

Can I set an alarm on Alexa or Google Home by sending a text message, through integration such as IFTTT?

From the ifttt website, the integration all seems to be driving actions through Alexa or Google Home, I am looking for ways to drive actions on Alexa or Assistant. 
https://ifttt.com/amazon_alexa
https://ifttt.com/google_assistant

Comment: i dunno if Alexa or Assistant have APIs for setting alarms. ask on their respective forums? SO is for programming questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Alexa I am sure you can't do it with the Alexa Skills Kit currently at Google Home I think you can't.

The simple Problem here is that both device react only on user voice for the normal developer.

At Alexa a Notification system is planned or already there but it seems that it can't be used by the normal developer, from Outside. So you can't send anything to the device. Only if the device request Something like after an Intent it can push this to notifications and even for that i am not sure.

What you can do is built your on Alexa | or maybe Google Assitant device with the Alexa Voice Service | maybe Google Assistant tools (dialogflow, action sdk etc.) but there you have to do all handshakes by yourself.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I found out too. There are feature requests on both Alexa and Google Home's developer forum, but yes, they are not currently available.

Answer (score 2):

Notifications (which are announced by a "bing" sound and a glowing yellow ring, and you listen to by saying, "Alexa, what are my notifications") can be pushed to your Alexa device using a skill I created called [Notify Me](https://amzn.to/2DZjj4u) and a REST API.

Notify Me works great with IFTTT via its Webhooks service. First, of course, you have to enable the Notify Me skill; then launch the skill to get an access code (say, "Alexa, launch Notify Me" and the skill will email you the access code). Next, you fill out the IFTTT Webhooks service like this...

**URL:** https://api.notifymyecho.com/v1/NotifyMe

**Method:** POST

**Content Type:** application/json

**Body:** {"notification": "HOWDY", "accessCode":"*ACCESS_CODE*"}

...replacing HOWDY with the actual message you want to send (it does not have to be all uppercase, of course) and replacing *ACCESS_CODE* with the access code you previously received via email.

See [www.notifymyecho.com](http://www.notifymyecho.com) for more info.

Comment: Sorry.  Yes, I created the Notify Me skill.  I get no compensation for its use, however.  I mainly made it for myself and am lucky enough to have Amazon let me share it with others (it was a tad difficult explaining what, exactly, it was).  It's not quite the "mass market" skill they are used to certifying.

Comment: Thanks very much for clarifying.